# Converting mkv to mp4 with ffmpeg sometimes loses video

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

How can I create a universal as possible command line to convert mkv to mp4?

I fixed an issue where sometimes I'd lose audio (I think) and now I'm losing video.
This is the command I currently use (I've used a few, including  `-analyzeduration 1G -probesize 50M` but I always end up with broken videos at some point):

```
if [[ $(pgrep -i ffmpeg) ]] ; then
  echo "FFMPEG IS ALREADY RUNNING!"
else 
  echo "Starting mkv to mp4 conversion...";
    for i in /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/*/*/*/*.mkv;
      do name=$(echo "${i//.mkv/}");
      echo "$name";
      ffmpeg -n -i "$i" -c copy -c:a aac -movflags +faststart "${name}.mp4"; rm -v -f "${name}.mkv";
    done
fi
```

Output of running that on the specific videos I'm losing picture on:

```
Starting mkv to mp4 conversion...
/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/Avatar The Last Airbender/Season 1/Avatar The Last Airbender - S01E02 - The Avatar Returns WEBDL-1080p
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-libjack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/Avatar The Last Airbender/Season 1/Avatar The Last Airbender - S01E02 - The Avatar Returns WEBDL-1080p.mkv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:23:59.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1258 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(tv), 1440x1080, 1124 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/Avatar The Last Airbender/Season 1/Avatar The Last Airbender - S01E02 - The Avatar Returns WEBDL-1080p.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(tv), 1440x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 1124 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 16k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
[mp4 @ 0x5583e9bdb8c0] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=34504 fps=1260 q=-1.0 Lsize=  221105kB time=00:23:59.08 bitrate=1258.6kbits/s speed=52.5x
video:197477kB audio:22515kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: 0.506059%
[aac @ 0x5583e9b3f140] Qavg: 562.538
```

Edit:

The below command worked on similar files which the above command did not:

```
  ffmpeg -n -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart
```

Output:

```
Starting mkv to mp4 conversion...
/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/Avatar The Last Airbender/Season 1/Avatar The Last Airbender - S01E03 - The Southern Air Temple WEBDL-1080p
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-libjack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/Avatar The Last Airbender/Season 1/Avatar The Last Airbender - S01E03 - The Southern Air Temple WEBDL-1080p.mkv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:24:10.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1354 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(tv), 1440x1080, 1124 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: eac3 (ec-3 / 0x332D6365), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (eac3 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] profile High 10, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 10-bit
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] 264 - core 157 r2980 34c06d1 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=34 lookahead_threads=5 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=23 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=81 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/Avatar The Last Airbender/Season 1/Avatar The Last Airbender - S01E03 - The Southern Air Temple WEBDL-1080p.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p10le, 1440x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
frame=   37 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.09 bitrate=   0.2kbits/sframe=   72 fps= 72 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.54 bitrate=   0.1kbits/sframe=  103 fps= 68 q=40.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.84 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  128 fps= 64 q=40.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:05.90 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  169 fps= 66 q=40.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:07.59 bitrate= 276.2kbits/frame=  194 fps= 63 q=40.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:08.66 bitrate= 484.3kbits/frame=  241 fps= 68 q=40.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:10.60 bitrate= 395.6kbits/frame=  262 fps= 64 q=40.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:11.47 bitrate= 365.5kbits/frame=  284 fps= 62 q=40.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:12.37 bitrate= 508.5kbits/frame=  312 fps= 61 q=40.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:13.54 bitrate= 464.5kbits/frame=  341 fps= 61 q=40.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:14.74 bitrate= 569.1kbits/frame=  373 fps= 61 q=40.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:16.10 bitrate= 651.0kbits/frame=  398 fps= 60 q=40.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:17.13 bitrate= 612.1kbits/frame=  419 fps= 59 q=40.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:18.02 bitrate= 698.0kbits/frame=  433 fps= 56 q=40.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:18.60 bitrate= 789.2kbits/frame=  456 fps= 55 q=40.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:19.56 bitrate= 857.6kbits/frame=  469 fps= 53 q=40.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:20.11 bitrate= 938.2kbits/frame=  486 fps= 52 q=40.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:20.82 bitrate=1108.0kbits/frame=  504 fps= 51 q=40.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:21.58 bitrate=1262.8kbits/frame=  522 fps= 51 q=40.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:22.31 bitrate=1503.7kbits/frame=  545 fps= 50 q=40.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:23.27 bitrate=1621.9kbits/frame=  570 fps= 50 q=40.0 size=    5120kB time=00:00:24.34 bitrate=1723.1kbits/frame=  597 fps= 50 q=40.0 size=    5632kB time=00:00:25.45 bitrate=1812.8kbits/frame=  619 fps= 50 q=40.0 size=    5888kB time=00:00:26.38 bitrate=1827.8kbits/frame=  650 fps= 50 q=40.0 size=    6400kB time=00:00:27.66 bitrate=1894.8kbits/frame=  674 fps= 50 q=40.0 size=    6656kB time=00:00:28.65 bitrate=1903.1kbits/frame=  701 fps= 50 q=40.0 size=    6656kB time=00:00:29.78 bitrate=1830.9kbits/frame=  734 fps= 51 q=40.0 size=    6912kB time=00:00:31.12 bitrate=1819.2kbits/frame=  754 fps= 50 q=40.0 size=    7168kB time=00:00:31.97 bitrate=1836.2kbits/frame=  778 fps= 50 q=40.0 size=    7168kB time=00:00:33.00 --SNIPPED--
bitrate=1518.4kbits/frame=34775 fps= 58 q=40.0 size=  268800kB time=00:24:10.64 bitrate=1518.0kbits/[mp4 @ 0x563ef7ad45c0] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=34783 fps= 58 q=-1.0 Lsize=  269967kB time=00:24:10.68 bitrate=1524.5kbits/s speed= 2.4x
video:246310kB audio:22689kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.359968%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] frame I:651   Avg QP:27.80  size: 60711
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] frame P:10705 Avg QP:32.02  size: 14279
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] frame B:23427 Avg QP:37.64  size:  2554
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] consecutive B-frames:  6.9%  8.1%  5.5% 79.6%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] mb I  I16..4: 29.6% 60.8%  9.6%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] mb P  I16..4:  7.7% 10.0%  1.1%  P16..4: 20.4%  3.8%  2.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:54.8%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] mb B  I16..4:  0.6%  0.6%  0.1%  B16..8: 13.6%  1.0%  0.2%  direct: 0.7%  skip:83.3%  L0:41.6% L1:55.3% BI: 3.1%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] 8x8 transform intra:54.2% inter:75.7%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 29.1% 50.3% 11.9% inter: 3.4% 4.5% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 29%  9% 38%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 18% 25%  4%  5%  5%  5%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 14% 17%  7%  8%  9%  6%  7%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 22% 19%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.7% UV:2.1%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] ref P L0: 74.1% 16.9%  8.9%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] ref B L0: 85.8% 11.6%  2.6%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] ref B L1: 96.8%  3.2%
[libx264 @ 0x563ef7ad5a40] kb/s:1390.85
[aac @ 0x563ef7ade100] Qavg: 572.905
removed '/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/Avatar The Last Airbender/Season 1/Avatar The Last Airbender - S01E03 - The Southern Air Temple WEBDL-1080p.mkv'
Done transcoding!
```

Comment: 1) How are you confirming that the video is lost or not working? The log indicates that the video was mapped and stream copied to the output. 2) Although the input extension is .mkv, ffmpeg (probably correctly) says it is MP4, so there may be no need to re-mux in the first place. Try just renaming it to .mp4. 3) The audio is already AAC. Recommend adding a check to avoid re-encoding existing AAC.

Comment: 1. To check, I’m just opening the video on my website and only getting sound. 2. Just renaming the videos is what lost audio previously, if I figure out how to check for AAC before running the command I could possibly see it working that way but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

The video **is** being included in your output (as shown in the `ffmpeg` log), but your browser does not like (10-bit) HEVC.

## Solutions

To fix this you can re-encode to H.264, VP9, AV1, or another format that your browser supports. Or use a [browser that supports HEVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support).

You can use `ffprobe` to determine the format(s) of the input. Example for the audio stream:

```
$ ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nw=1 input.mp4
codec_name=aac
```

Use `-of default=nw=1:nk=1` if you want to get rid of `codec_name=` in the output.

This will allow you to easily use if/then statements in your bash script to avoid unnecessary re-encoding.

Comment: I will update my script to test the audio/video and use the output to decide where to go from there. Thank you for helping me to understand what was going wrong.

Comment: @RobertW If you re-encode to H.264 and browser doesn't like 10-bit then add `-vf format=yuv420p` to the command.